# php paypal checkout multiple items

Tags: php, html, paypal, paypal-sandbox

i write a simple cart, and now i want to integrate Paypal.

This is my Paypal code (Top = without $counter and Bottom with $counter):

```
        echo "<input type='hidden' name='item_name_1' value='$items'>";
        echo "<input type='hidden' name='amount_1' value='1.00'>";
        echo "<input type='hidden' name='item_name_2' value='$items'>";
        echo "<input type='hidden' name='amount_2' value='2.00'>";
```

---

```
     foreach(Session::get('p_name') as $items) 
     {
      echo $items;
      echo $counter;
      echo "<input type='hidden' name='item_name_.$counter.' value='$items'>";
      echo "<input type='hidden' name='amount_1' value='1.00'>";
      echo "<input type='hidden' name='item_name_.$counter.' value='$items'>";
      echo "<input type='hidden' name='amount_2' value='2.00'>";

    $counter++;
    }
```

I want that for every Value in "$items" (Values are: Item1, Item2) to write a line in Paypal.

With my Paypal code with $counter he say: "Your Cart is empty".
What should I change?

Comment: "amount_1" should be dynamic as "amount_.$counter".

Comment: and the amount_2 (and second item_name) is not needed anymore.

Comment: i changed the amount_ and deleted the 2nd item_name and amount, but he still say: "Your shopping cart is empty."

Comment: change input type "text" from "hidden" and just see the form. is value in form display correctly ??

Comment: with "type = text" he show me the values correctly

Comment: https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=p/pdn/howto_checkout-outside  visit this website and see where is mistake

Comment: i looked @ paypal/../howto_checkout... but cant find my mistake. As type=text everything looks fine, but he detect an error and say: "Your shopping cart is empty."

Comment: after testing this code seems wrong => name='item_name_.$counter.'

Comment: fixed. changed to name='item_number_$counter' and now it works!